# CSS Transitions not running on jQuery modal

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

This is probably the least difficult issue I have delbt with this week. I am dynamically loading data from a JSON and filling in fields within a Modal.  Being the lover of User Experience I want the Modal to scale in. Im open to changes to this script that being it successfully does what I need it to do.

The Issue
When you open the Modal (by clicking the title). jQuery adds .active to the parent (overlay) which begins the process. When the modal opens the Inner (modal-pop-content) is already scaled in 1 instead of starting at 1. I have done delay. And also in my JS I used css to inline add the transform: scale(1).

Here is the codepen I am working on.
https://codepen.io/designsbycamaron/pen/ROzZWj

css is where the issue is at.

```
.area-pop.active {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    left: 0;
    opacity:1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.area-pop.active .modal-pop-content {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
}
.modal-pop-content {
    width: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 400px;
    background-position: 30% center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

I have tried most everything. Again.. if you have a better solution I am open to it. I may just do a fade transition. But I feel I would have the same problem.

Thank you community!

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by adding `scale(1)` to `.modal-pop-content.active` Then add the `active` class to modal content just **after** `.area-pop` is shown by using `setTimeout()`

```js
$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.area-pop').removeClass('active');
  $('.modal-pop-content').removeClass('active');
});

$('.modal-click').click(function() {
  $('.area-pop').addClass('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.modal-pop-content').addClass('active');
  }, 50);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.area-pop.active {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-pop-content.active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
}

.modal-pop-content {
  width: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 400px;
  background-position: 30% center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
}

h2.modal-pop-title,
.modal-pop-content .content-area {
  color: #fff;
}

.modal-pop-content .content-area {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 28px;
  display: flex;
}

.emp-photo img {
  width: 90%;
}

.emp-photo {
  width: 50%;
}

.emp-content-area {
  width: 70%;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  right: 30%;
  top: 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.area-pop:not(.active) {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

h3.emp-title a {
  color: #000;
}

h3.emp-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-bc3e463 elementor-widget elementor-widget-image is-mac" data-id="bc3e463" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="image.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
      <div class="elementor-image">
        <img width="170" height="239" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/17/Bugs_Bunny.svg/220px-Bugs_Bunny.svg.png" class="attachment-full size-full" alt=""> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-2db4bcd elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor is-mac" data-id="2db4bcd" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
      <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix">
        <h3 class="emp-title"><a href="#" data-attr="john smith" class="modal-click">John Smith</a></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="area-pop">
  <div class="close">X</div>
  <div class="modal-pop-content" style="">
    <h2 class="modal-pop-title">JOHN SMITH</h2>
    <div class="content-area">
      <div class="emp-photo"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/17/Bugs_Bunny.svg/220px-Bugs_Bunny.svg.png"></div>
      <div class="emp-content-area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce luctus, tellus ut feugiat aliquet, urna metus cursus neque, a placerat quam ipsum vel augue. Nunc pellentesque euismod massa eu commodo. Ut at nulla mauris. Duis nisi mi, gravida vitae
        ornare nec, porta non ligula. Phasellus non arcu blandit, commodo sapien quis, vestibulum orci. Donec eu sollicitudin lectus. Aliquam scelerisque, nisi a accumsan volutpat, erat orci cursus nulla, in laoreet arcu libero non elit. Sed tincidunt,
        ante ut finibus egestas, mauris ante mollis quam, id scelerisque erat tortor eu massa. Aliquam eu justo ex. Donec vitae elit cursus, efficitur turpis sit amet, aliquet turpis. Vestibulum vel accumsan nunc. In aliquam felis ac tortor viverra, eget
        tempus tortor ullamcorper. In a porttitor odio. Aenean sollicitudin est eu risus faucibus, sit amet imperdiet arcu ornare.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmmm, I had thought about using setTimeout but I was really wanting to limit the amount of js involved in producing the outcome. But it looks like it works. Ill plug it in and try. Thank you!